# UnrecognizedPropertyException ao ler firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Recebi o erro e não sei mais o que fazer:

Erro

> 01 19:15:53.568 21966 21966 D   AndroidRuntime
>   Shutting down VM 09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E
>   AndroidRuntime                               Process:
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao, PID: 21966 09-01 19:15:53.574 21966
>   21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type 09-01
>   19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.MainActivity$100000001$100000000.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:71)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 09-01
>   19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 09-01
>   19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 09-01 19:15:53.574 21966
>   21966 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 09-01
>   19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 09-01 19:15:53.574
>   21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 09-01
>   19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "-KszUQXLaFg5qrTIXqAs" (class
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.model.Person), not marked as ignorable
>   (3 known properties: , "uid", "name", "address"]) 09-01 19:15:53.574
>   21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   [Source: java.io.StringReader@a6ef5a3; line: 1, column: 56] (through
>   reference chain:
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.model.Person["-KszUQXLaFg5qrTIXqAs"])
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
>   09-01 19:15:53.574 21966 21966 E   AndroidRuntime
>   ... 11 more

Objeto

```
package com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.model;

import com.google.firebase.database.*;


/**
* Created by Belal on 2/23/2016.
*/ //@JsonIgnoreProperties @IgnoreExtraProperties  public class Person { //name and address string 

private String name; private String address; @Exclude private String uid;

public Person() { /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/ } //Getters and setters public String getUid(){ return uid; }

public void setUid(String uId) { this.uid = uId; }


public String getName() { return name; }

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

public String getAddress() { return address; }

public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }

}

Código buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {

String personId; //Creating firebase object Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

//Getting values to store String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim(); String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();


//Creating Person object Person person = new Person();

personId = ref.push().getKey();

//Adding values person.setName(name); person.setAddress(address); //person.setUid(personId);

//Storing values to firebase //ref.child("Person").setValue(person);


ref.child("Person").child(personId).setValue(person);


//Value event listener for realtime data update ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) { for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) { //Getting the data from snapshot Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

//Adding it to a string String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

//Displaying it on textview textViewPersons.setText(string); } }

@Override public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage()); } });

} });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fala amigo,tente manipular os valores dentro dos métodos do firebase,:por exemplo os gettext.tostring.Evite trabalhar passando parâmetros para os métodos sobrescrito do firebase. Seu código está meio confuso, se puder dar uma ajeitada.eu consiga analisar melhor

Comment: Olá oto, obrigado por responder. Alterei o código e agora ele funciona. Agora eu não sei o que fazer com a pergunta que fiz. Devo substituir o conteúdo pelo novo código? Alguma outra opção? Obrigado mais uma vez pela sua atenção.

Comment: Você da um up na minha resposta pra dizer que ela te ajudou

Comment: @UltraSeven coloque o novo código como uma resposta. E marque ela como aceite.